# printer drives for canon printers

Tags: printing, canon

I am having all kind of trouble using canon E484 printer. The only way I can print is via my IPhone or any other smart phone. I send documents to be printed to a smart phone and send print order through. Any suggestions how a can print in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

if one goes here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100666902.html and clicks to download and SAVE what will be cnijfilter2-5.10-1-deb.tar.gz issued 5th Feb 2015. Then open a terminal; copy each line below; one by one; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.10-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter2-5.10-1-deb
```

then run the install script, and watch it work; it will ask questions of you

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

that should 1) install the drivers and 2) register the printer with ladmin